# Placeholder Videos for HTML Wireframes/Mockups

Tags: video, wireframe, mockups

Is there any site that hosts placeholder videos that can be used for HTML mockups?  There are a few for images (such as [LoremPixum](http://lorempixel.com/)), but I have not been able to find any for videos.

Comment: Did you ever find one? I've been using Big Buck Bunny as shown on the [Video For Everybody test page](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody/test.html), but my students hate seeing this thing. I'm wondering if there isn't something more interesting, or even more plain like http://placehold.it

Comment: Sadly no.  I ended up just loading some random videos onto my own Amazon S3 account and using those URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I would think just a simple, 5-second .mp4 or .webm (or both) video would do the trick. Or do you need a video that says "Lorem ipsum"? :-)